# What is the limit of $\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{x^4e^{-4x} +2x^2}{x^{-2}\ln(x)-x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am looking for the limit of :

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{x^4e^{-4x} +2x^2}{x^{-2}\ln(x)-x}$$

And I found    $$\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{x^4e^{-4x} +2x^2}{x^{-2}\ln(x)-x}=+\infty$$

I'm not sure of the result.

Comment: Is it $x^4e-4x$  or $x^4e^{-4x}$?

Comment: @Bernard Form the typing it was clearly $x^4e^{-4x}$, I've edited it.

Comment: @user: Thanks. I thought so, but one never knows…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$ \frac{x^4e^{-4x} +2x^2}{x^{-2}\ln(x)-x}=\frac{x^3e^{-4x} +2x}{\frac{\ln(x)}x-1} \to -\infty$$

indeed

$$x^3e^{-4x}=\frac{x^3}{e^{4x}} \to 0, \quad\frac{\ln(x)}x\to 0$$

Answer (score 2):

With *equivalents*, it's instantaneous: the numerator is symptotically equivalent to $2x^2$, the denominator to $-x$, so 
$$\frac{x^4e^{-4x} +2x^2}{x^{-2}\ln(x)-x}\sim_{+\infty}\frac{2x^2}{-x}=-2x\to-\infty.$$